# how to assign javascript variable value to php variable in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript

I use following way to fetch the value of gtag if it already exists in the code:

```
        <script>
        const regex = /googletagmanager\.com\/gtag\/js\?id=([^\s'"]+)/gi;

        const scriptTags = document.querySelectorAll('script');
                let trackingID = ''; 
                scriptTags.forEach(script => {
                    const src = script.getAttribute('src');
                     if (src && src.includes('googletagmanager.com/gtag/js')) {
                        const match = regex.exec(src);
                     if (match && match.length > 1) {
                        trackingID = match[1];
                     }
                   }
                });
        </script>
```

Now I want the **trackingID** to be printed in the following script if it exists else print the code value that exists

```
<script async src="<?php echo ( $local_analytics_file ?? 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=' ) . '?' . esc_html( $UA_CODE ); ?>"></script>
```

Need something like

```
<script async src="<?php echo ( $local_analytics_file ?? 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=+if(trackingID) trackingID' ) . '?' . esc_html( $UA_CODE ); ?>"></script>
```

And similarly in following

```
<script>
            console.log('Google Analytics Tracking ID:', trackingID);

            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            const configuration = JSON.parse( '<?php echo $configuration; ?>' );
            const gaID = '<?php echo esc_html( $UA_CODE ); ?>'; // I want trackingID to be printed if available else print the $UA_CODE
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't possible. You'll need to do it all in JavaScript.

Comment: Your JS runs on the browser. By that time PHP is all wrapped up. This is not gonna fly.

Comment: any fixes? @vancoder